# Multiple Upload tool, script or plugin?

Tags: php, javascript, flash

I'm trying to make an upload function in this website I'm working on, but till now no succes.

I tried using Plupload, but can't get it to work. Same goes for Uploadify, can't find any tutorial or good explanation in how to install these plugins in your webpage.
Does anybody know a good and easy to use multiple upload tool I can easily implement in the page?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't get much easier than [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/). What's going wrong when you try to use it?

Comment: @thirtydot; When I open the uploadify.php file and launch it, it's empty. No Idea on how to use it, if you can help me out, it would be much appreciated. How can I install/use the module?

Comment: That's not how you do it. You don't open `uploadify.php` - that file is called by the Flash part of Uploadify. You need to carefully read the instructions here: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/ - it's already giving detailed exact instructions, such as "Save a new page to the root directory of your website and paste the following code".

Comment: @thirtydot; Ok I got it to work now, but the files aren't uploaded in the directory. The directory user have all the rights so I don't see the problem. Any idea on what's going wrong?

Comment: @thirtydot; Nevermind, removed the `/`and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot, if you add an answer I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from the comments on the question:

> It doesn't get much easier than
>   [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/).

See here for detailed instructions: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this little [thingy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/dojo-multifile-uploader-with-flash).

it is very easy to implement and works very well for me.

it uses the Dojo toolkit - i think you should check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/valums/file-uploader, has a nice readme, and supports drag and drop in some browsers.